# How to retrieve post and get request values in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, request

I am creating Extention and I need to send posts and get requests. I want to fetch that variables values that are sent using get or post method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For single parameter, use:

```
$req = $this->getRequest()->getParam('param_name');
```

For all parameters, use:

```
$req = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

for post method you get values

```
$posts = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
print_r($posts);
```

for get method you get values

```
$gets = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
print_r($gets);
```

for single get value

```
$gets = $this->getRequest()->getParam('variable_name');
print_r($gets);
```